# NullPointerException When Writing to a RandomAccessFile

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, randomaccessfile

I can write to the random access file directly after I create it but as soon as I try to write from my function then it breaks.

```
private void openFile()
{
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

    fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY );
    int result = fileChooser.showSaveDialog( this );

    // user clicked Cancel button on dialog
    if ( result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION )
    {
        return;
    }

    File fileName = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

    if ( fileName == null || fileName.getName().equals( "" ) )
    {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( this,
        "Invalid File Name",
        "Invalid File Name",
        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
    }
    else 
    {
     // Open the file
        try 
        {
            RandomAccessFile output = new RandomAccessFile( fileName, "rw" );
            createRecord();
        }
        catch ( IOException e ) 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( this,
            "File does not exist",
            "Invalid File Name",
            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
        }      
    }
}

private void createRecord()
{
    String firstName = tfdFirst.getText();
    String lastName = tfdLast.getText();
    String emailAddress = tfdEmail.getText();
    String homeAddress = tfdAddress.getText();
    Long phoneNumber = new Long(tfdPhone.getText());
    char gender = tfdGender.getText().charAt(0);

    System.out.println(firstName + lastName + emailAddress + homeAddress + phoneNumber + gender);

    try
    {
        output.seek(0);
        output.writeChar(gender);
        writeString( output, lastName);
        writeString( output, firstName);
        writeString( output, emailAddress);
        writeString( output, homeAddress);
        output.writeLong(phoneNumber);
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Sorry for the wall of code, but those are the two offending functions. The first tries to open a RandomAccessFile called output, before calling `createRecord()` which tries to write user input from a JFrame to the file. If I put a simple `writeInt()` function in the place of `createRecord()` then it works okay but once `createRecord()` is called it's as if output never existed.

I've been working at this for hours to no avail, so if someone could help find a solution I would be very grateful.

Edit: Stack Trace as requested. (Warning, very long...)

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at good_gals_customer_app.NewCustomerUI.createRecord(NewCustomerUI.java:298)
at good_gals_customer_app.NewCustomerUI.openFile(NewCustomerUI.java:273)
at good_gals_customer_app.NewCustomerUI.butCreateRecordActionPerformed(NewCustomerUI.java:186)
at good_gals_customer_app.NewCustomerUI.access$100(NewCustomerUI.java:21)
at good_gals_customer_app.NewCustomerUI$2.actionPerformed(NewCustomerUI.java:87)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Stack trace please, also point out the line that is causing the NPE

Comment: I don't even see how this code compiles; `output` is undeclared in `createRecord()`

Comment: @fge And there is the problem, `output` is likely an instance field

Comment: Oh sorry, output is declared in the class that holds these functions. The lines causing the NPE are where I try to write to the file in createRecord.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have, what appears to be, a shadowing problem...

You've created a local variable `output` in `openFile`...

```
RandomAccessFile output = new RandomAccessFile( fileName, "rw" );
```

But are access, what appears to be an instance variable in `createRecord`...

```
output.seek(0);
```

In all likelihood, the instance variable is `null`...

Normally, I would suggest removing the redeclaration and using the instance field, but in the this, I think you should get rid of the instance field and pass a reference of the `RandomAccessFile` to the `createRecord` method

You're also not managing your resources, remember if you open, you must close it...

```
try (RandomAccessFile output = new RandomAccessFile( fileName, "rw" ))
{
    createRecord(output);
}
catch ( IOException e ) 
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( this,
    "File does not exist",
    "Invalid File Name",
    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
}
```

Take a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for more details

Comment: Thank you! That works now. Also, I was planning on adding the close code later, I wanted to make sure I could write first.

Comment: Not closing the file could cause the file not be flushed, so long as you're aware ;)